# Adding a inner join to this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which I found a modified version of it online. I have another table called contacts and I am trying to inner join l.id with c.email. I don't normally use subqueries so what I found online seems foreign to me.

In any case, how can I add a inner join where l.id = c.lead_id as I need to select c.email.

```
SELECT l.id, 
(SELECT amount FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND buyer = 'BUYER_PROXY') AS our_bid,
(SELECT amount FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND buyer != 'BUYER_PROXY' AND discriminator='AUTO_PING' ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) AS best_bid,
(SELECT amount FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND winner = 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) AS final_sold_amount,
(SELECT buyer FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND winner = 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) AS buyer
FROM leads AS l
WHERE l.state = 'ACCEPTED'
AND (SELECT buyer FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND winner = 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) != 'TEST'
AND DATE(l.create_date) > '2011-12-01'
```

I know, the question isn't clear, but can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close:

```
SELECT l.id, 
(SELECT amount FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND buyer = 'BUYER_PROXY') AS our_bid,
(SELECT amount FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND buyer != 'BUYER_PROXY' AND discriminator='AUTO_PING' ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) AS best_bid,
(SELECT amount FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND winner = 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) AS final_sold_amount,
(SELECT buyer FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND winner = 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) AS buyer,
c.email
FROM leads AS l
INNER JOIN contacts AS c ON l.id = c.lead_id
WHERE l.state = 'ACCEPTED'
AND (SELECT buyer FROM lead_status WHERE lead_id = l.id AND discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND winner = 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1) != 'TEST'
AND DATE(l.create_date) > '2011-12-01'
```

INNER JOIN is just like adding another table, first you have your original "FROM" table, then INNER JOIN (or variants) the others.